# double click to open file in my program created in godot

Tags: file, operating-system, godot, gdscript

How do I create an application with the Godot engine that reads a file with the extension .ccc, for example, by simply clicking on the file twice, like the rest of the programs we know , I do not want the entire code to run the program because I have already completed it, meaning the program can create .ccc files and read them by entering the file path of the file by the user

What I want is just the piece of code that will make the .ccc files open automatically by my program when double clicking on them

I have already associated the .ccc extension with my program in the operating system, and this only makes the files lead to opening the program, but they are not opened by the program. I have to put code inside gdscript to receive parameters from the operating system, which will be the file path. I implemented this idea with C++ and it succeeded, so I hope to find a way to implement it using gdscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the command line arguments using [`OS.get_cmdline_args()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-cmdline-args) in Godot 4 or [`OS.get_cmdline_args()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-cmdline-args) in Godot 3.

It will return an string array (more precisely a `PackedStringArray` in Godot 4 and a `PoolStringArray` in Godot 3), so you can iterate over it and see which arguments you got.

Try it, see how are you get the file path, and work from there.

Comment: thanks i used  OS.get_cmdline_user_args()  to get the command line arguments But it doesn't work but  OS.get_cmdline_args()  works